# Laravel - multiple controllers with same name

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, controller, namespaces

I already have a working application and there is a `PhoneController.php` in controllers folder.

Now I want to add an api for my application so I added `api\v1\PhoneController.php`

But when I use routing this doesnt work as I want to:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
    Route::get('test', 'PhoneController@index');
});
```

I tried adding `'namespace' => 'api\v1'` or `api\v1\PhoneController@index` but this always picks the wrong PhoneController.

Are there anyways to get it work? I could rename the `PhoneController.php` but this could confuse me in future, so I am trying to avoid this solution

Comment: http://daylerees.com/codebright/controllers in Controller Routing he speaks about namespacing controllers

Comment: A quick question: when I always use this way I have to add a lot of these use XYZ; over and over again, are there ways to automate this?

Comment: put \ before classname ex: \View

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks! Can I mark your answer as correct answer?

Comment: I added an answer, happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described here http://daylerees.com/codebright/controllers

```
namespace Blog\Controller;

class Article extends \BaseController
{
    public function showIndex()
    {
        return \View::make('index');
    }
}
```

Then add route

```
Route::post('index', 'Blog\Controller\Article@showIndex');
```